# How to add Multi Language Support in Oracle jet Hybrid Application

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-jet

I would like to know about adding multi language support in `oracle jet application`.  I have tried with google translate code but its not working also tried to change the language attribute of `html` like :

> eg:.   html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar"
>   lang="ar".

By using this only the date picker has changed to the specified language.

Kindly help me with a solution to add multi language support to `oracle jet application`.

Thanks,

Regards,
Janani

Comment: Save your strings in a database stored under different language tables and then just fill them in when creating your html? Surely Oracle has some kind of templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

When locale is specified on the HTML tag and if that locale doesn't have an associated resource bundle in JET libs then Oracle JET loads a default bundle or less significant bundle. From your description looks like it is loading a default one. Please refer to below link to add a customized resource bundle for your locale and add all the required translations.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet112/jet/developer/GUID-F3E45F96-FAE2-4830-A2FA-16B3740B1A2D.htm